# How can make CURL waits until it finished?

Tags: curl

When I perform curl command with API to get somethings in large database. Curl immediately returns the process number and after some minutes it returns the result

> curl --netrc <my_API>
>
> [1] 24516 -> process ID
>
> ... After some minutes, it returns the result ...
>
> {   "results" : ... }

How can I make curl waits until it returns result?

Comment: which OS are you using? are you running the command from command line?

Comment: You probably need to put the  <my_API> part in quotes - bash sees the & character and puts the curl process in the background

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and run from command line.
Yes. You are right @DobromirVelev when it sees & and put curl process as background but use double quote still not help. It returns result immediately, not wait so result is empty.

Comment: can you run the curl command with -v to check what is happening. May be the API returns something that closes the connection, usually curl will wait. You might try increasing the max time with -m